# not sure how apply easing with jquery shake effect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-effects

I have been working on this in [jsfiddle`Txh7R`](http://jsfiddle.net/Txh7R/148/) it is working fine but i would like to apply easing such that it doesn't shake the div too aggressively. I want it to be smoother, much like the toggling banner from this site http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_33599/

It may very well be that shaking effect is not the best thing to use, fairly new to jquery so suggestions would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: You can try adding the option 'duration: 1000' which will slow down the shaking.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the easing effects according to your need from here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-shake.htm
Hope this helps

Comment: Please include relevant content in the answer itself.  Link-Only answers can become stale if the link fails.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript
jQuery with the jQuery Easing Plugin is the easiest way to describe animation with easing. Pass the easing name (like easeInCirc) to the .animate() function as the third argument, or use it as the value of the easing option.

```
div.animate({ top: '-=100px' }, 600, 'easing name', function () { … })
```